# Are shell aliases POSIX compliant?

Tags: shell, posix, alias

I am writing a utility which lets you set shell aliases persistently.

I have it in my head that unix shell aliases are POSIX compliant, but I can't remember where I heard this and my google fu has not yielded any definitive answer.

Most of my experience is with zsh and bash.

Is it safe to assume that if I write aliases in the format of specified by both bash and zsh, that I'll be able to port this format over to other shells?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`alias`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/alias.html) (and  `unalias`) are indeed in POSIX.

See also [alias substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_03_01) and [alias names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_10) for how they are supposed to be implemented.